# 12V fans in series with 25 A supply

Tags: voltage, current, series

I'm trying to set up a relayed cooling mechanism for a mass spectrometer (i.e. cooling fans turn on when the MS exceeds a certain temperature). I have a **24V DC/25A power** supply which converts 100-120V AC/12 A to 24V at multiple output leads, and that will be connected to several different instruments.

I just purchased 2 cooling fans - **12V DC/85mA** - and would like to connect these in **series** to the power supply. However, when I connected them, they simply shuddered and did not turn on. Not to displace blame (I accept full accountability for the fans not working/not fully checking the specs), but it appears as though the company from whom I bought the fans did not specify that the nominal voltage range was about 10-14V.

The reason I bought the 12V fans specifically was because I thought the voltage would drop over each device - but perhaps not? I also want to make sure that I leave enough power for other small devices to operate off of the same supply.

So, what I would like to know if there is anything I can do? Should I simply return the fans for a 24V alternative? Or to save the cost of shipping, is there anything to make these fans work? I've read about using a diode to drop the voltage, but would that be the best option? It also appears to me as though a resistor would not do the trick.

Thanks **very much** in advance.

R

Comment: What they said and/but as well as 2 x capacitors try a slightly higher than 12V zener diode (say 13.2V) across one fan only. A fan dissipates about 12v x 85 mA ~+ 1 Watt so if the fan it is across drew nothing a 1W zener will supply ~~ 12V to the other fan while being at about its max rating. Once the fans are running, if well balanced, neither zener will conduct significantly. (1 x 13.2V zener across each fan should be OK - but ensure they do not conduct significantly at Vinmax/2. )

Comment: Thanks very much for all of the help/responses - much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect they will start working if you put a capacitor from the center point to ground. Maybe about 330 or 470uF.

Each of the fans has an electronic circuit which pulses the  coil in the motor to start a rotating field. Without a good ground for the upper fan (or without a good Vcc for the other one) this logic circuit won't work well.

It's not an ideal situation, as on Power-On, the top motor will then receive 24V for a fraction of a second.

EDIT: @Asmyldof posted a good comment: Use two capacitors in series over the 24V supply and the center to the center of the fans. That'll keep the center..., well, centered.

Comment: I'd make that two caps of the same value, one across each fan, forming a HF-voltage divider, allowing quicker and better stabilisation. Very likely one will do well enough, though.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more complex (4 junk box parts) solution, but safer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgDQx2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the output goes lower than 11.3V D2 conducts and supplies current from U1. 
If the output goes higher than 12.7V Q3 conducts and sinks current (U1/R1 sinks the base current of Q3 but not a much higher current).

This allows asymmetrical startup current to be supplied, but does not draw much current during normal run. Even if one fan is completely removed, the other will continue to run (though U1 or Q3 will get hot). 7812 could be replaced with a 1N4742 (1W 12V zener) from +24 to D2.

Answer (score 0):

This undesirable behavior most probably happens because the fans are driven by brushless motors. Brushless motors do not have "constant" and predictable current consumption as conventional DC brush motors do.

As your power supply is 24V 25A, I would simply test **how a resistive voltage divider would work in parallel with the fans**, equalizing the voltages with a "side-current" of 120mA (150% of stated 85mA consumption) passing through the resistors, as illustrated below.
[image]

I divided each balancing branch into two series resistors of 1Watt each, to make it smaller and easier to find, each 47R running at 0.76W. When the fan motors start running, most imbalance and current transients that *Fan1* could inflict into *Fan2* (or vice-versa) are to be attenuated by the equalizing resistors.

A **lower consumption approach** would be to use a larger resistor (as 150R~220R) with an electrolytic capacitor (as 1000uF x 25V) in parallel with each fan. Consumption and heat dissipation will be lower too, but 2 capacitors cost more and use more space than 2x 1W resistors.

Let us know which solutions worked for you, ok?